# Div wrapping even though i'm using overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

Im trying to create a header with different images and their deiscription. I want their description to be shown when we mouseOver the content using jQuery. I'm only posting my HTML and CSS as i think thats where the problem lies.

jQuery works but the problem is that even after using overflow hidden the div with class headerCont wraps around to next line. Can someone help me with this.  Thanks.

Im not allowed to post images so this is the link to image that will help you in understanding me ->

http://image.bayimg.com/cabjpaaeg.jpg

http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/3236/cabjpaaeg.jpg

PS in the above image i've mouseOver one of the div with class headerCont. I want the TEXT to be placed next to the image. Also the last div wraps over to next line whenever one of the div is expanded (dont know the correct word to explain that!) instead of its original place

The HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Silder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div style="margin: 5px; width:1300px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="headerCont" style="background-color: #cdcdcd;  ">
            <div><img src="image/1.jpg" style="height: 317px; width: 214px; float:left; " /></div>
            <div style="float:left;margin-left:214px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Discription </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headerCont" style="background-color: #719501; ">
            <div><img src="image/2.jpg" style="height: 317px; width: 214px;" /></div>
            <div style="float:left; position:absolute ;margin-left:214px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Discription </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headerCont" style="background-color: #f3f3f3; ">
            <div><img src="image/3.jpg" style="height: 317px; width: 214px;" /></div>
            <div style="float:left; position:absolute ;margin-left:214px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Discription </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headerCont" style="background-color: #719501; ">
            <div><img src="image/4.jpg" style="height: 317px; width: 214px;" /></div>
            <div style="float:left; position:absolute ;margin-left:186px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Discription </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headerCont" style="background-color: #f3f3f3;">
            <div><img src="image/5.jpg" style="height: 317px; width: 214px;" /></div>
            <div style="float:left; position:absolute ;margin-left:214px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Discription </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js" ></script>
</body>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#content{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 90%;
border: 2px solid;
border-color: #272727;}
.outter{
border:2px solid #000000;
margin:4px;
position: relative;
}
.header{
width:1300px;
height:400px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
margin-bottom:20px;
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
}
.headerCont{
height: 100%; 
width:214px;
padding:5px;  
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
.header img{
border-color:#000000;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".headerCont").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).animate({
width:400,
  }, 300 );
});

$(".headerCont").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).animate({ 
width: 214,
  }, 200 );
});
```

Comment: I would highly encourage you to post your home.js code simply because I am still a little confused as to what your site is doing and/or what you're trying to accomplish. The image you posted also gives a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Ive posted my javascript and another link for my image. I hope it works this time

Comment: Image is 403 - Forbidden

Comment: try copying and then pasting it in the URL. Dont know why but that works for me. i have even posted another link from imageshack that should help

Comment: Just a little more clarification so all you want is the text to appear  next to the div when you mouseover the div? Not to find a way around your problem, but I suggest taking a look at [Jquery's Tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) as I think it is what you're trying to achieve (and it's a lot easier than just making it yourself).

Comment: Yes i want the text to appear next to the div when i mouseover. And i really think that the problem is in my css or html because i unlink the javascript and the page still wasnt the way i wanted it to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out the solution. thanks everyone else. all i did was add another wrapper div after my header div. Here the code:

```
<div class="header">
            <div style="width:10000px; height: 317px;">
            <div class="outter">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="image1.jpg" height="317px" width="217px"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;">Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="outter">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="image1.jpg" height="317px" width="217px"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;">Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="outter">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="image1.jpg" height="317px" width="217px"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;">Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="outter">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="image1.jpg" height="317px" width="217px"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;">Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="outter">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="image1.jpg" height="317px" width="217px"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;">Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="outter">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="image1.jpg" height="317px" width="217px"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;">Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="outter">
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="image1.jpg" height="317px" width="217px"/></div>
                <div style="float:left;">Description</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```